# Is the function foreach only available in the foreach package?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

The "foreach" package has, essentially, the foreach function. Is this function only available in this package?
Does the parallel package include the foreach function? And the doParallel package? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get all functions from any package visiting [`CRAN`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html). `parallel` package does not have `foreach` function.

foreach package does no have only `foreach` function. And yes, it's only available (until today) in foreach package. You can check by doing `??foreach` in you R console.

Take a look at its help [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/foreach.pdf).

Comment: I visited the CRAN page and in the doParallel package documentation it says _"Depends: R (≥ 2.14.0), foreach (≥ 1.2.0), iterators (≥ 1.0.0), parallel, utils"_
Does this mean that the foreach package is included in doParallel?

Comment: `Depends` means that package {doParallel} has access to all functions in the package {foreach} and that when you load {doParallel}, it will also load {foreach}.